# trying to use multiple search with jqgrid but only single search GUI pops up

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

i want to implement more advance search than the filter toolbar in jqgrid so i changed my code to set multipleSearch: true:

```
jQuery("#grid").navGrid("#pager",
        { multipleSearch:true, add: false, edit: false, del: false },
        {}, {}, {}, {}
```

i do get the Search Icon in my footer toolbar
[image]

but when i click on it, i just get the single field search GUI. 
[image]

does anyone know why this would not show up the multiple search GUI?  Am i missing some extra plugin or config setting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `multipleSearch:true` inside another parameter of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition):

```
jQuery("#grid").navGrid("#pager",
        { add: false, edit: false, del: false }, // navGrid options
        {}, // edit option
        {}, // add options
        {}, // del options
        {multipleSearch:true}  // !!! search options !!!
);
```